# DLL needed after assembly creation?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sqlclr

Can I delete the DLL-File C:\PATH\TO\DLL\FILE.DLL after creating an assembly with

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY MyAssemblyName FROM 'C:\PATH\TO\DLL\FILE.DLL'
```

?

Everything seems to work fine after deleting the file. But

```
SELECT * FROM sys.assembly_files
```

shows the path of the file in the name column. Can this cause problems? (or is the content of the DLL stored in the database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assembly bits are transfered into the database, the original DLL location is irelevant. The idea is that an SQL loaded assembly should continue to work after a backup and restore on a different machine, it has to be entirely contained inside the database.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually stored in [sys.assembly_files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175085(SQL.90).aspx) so can be deleted

This means it's an integral part of the database through backuo/restore, attach/detach etc